# Python replace one character between two character and keep rest

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to replace a comma that is in between two known character(`§`)

My test string: `'§Bandra(West),Mumbai§'`

The expected output: `'§Bandra(West);Mumbai§'`

I tried:

```
re.sub(r'\§[^\,]+\,[^\,]+\§',r'\§[^\,]+\;[^\,]+\§', '§Bandra(West),Mumbai§')
```

But that just returns my regular expression as string: `\§[^\',']+\;[^\',']+\§`

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression,

```
(§[^§\r\n]*),([^§\r\n]*§)
```

and a replacement of,

```
\1;\2
```

might simply work here.

#### Test

```
import re

string = """
§Bandra(West);Mumbai§
§Bandra(West),Mumbai§
§,§
Bandra(West),Mumbai§
"""

print(re.sub(r'(§[^§\r\n]*),([^§\r\n]*§)', r"\1;\2", string))
```

#### Output

```
§Bandra(West);Mumbai§
§Bandra(West);Mumbai§
§;§
Bandra(West),Mumbai§
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cjrnu5/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/cjrnu5/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 1):

You want regular expression **groups**, which are created with parentheses then referenced with a backslash and a number:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(§[^,]+),([^,]+§)', r'\1;\2', '§Bandra(West),Mumbai§')
'§Bandra(West);Mumbai§'
```

Here `(§[^,]+)` corresponds to `\1` and `([^,]+§)` corresponds to `\2`.

More info: [`re` - Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) under `(...)` and `\number`

By the way:

- You had a bunch of unecessary backslashes that I removed.
- In this particular example, you could use a simpler pattern:

  ```
  >>> re.sub(r'(§.*),(.*§)', r'\1;\2', '§Bandra(West),Mumbai§')
  '§Bandra(West);Mumbai§'
  ```

  or even a simple `.replace`:

  ```
  >>> '§Bandra(West),Mumbai§'.replace(',', ';')
  '§Bandra(West);Mumbai§'
  ```